# count records in ms access using query

Tags: sql, ms-access

how to count record in ms access? here are my tables

```
[basicinfo](table1)
[Name     age     rawscore](fields)
mark      16      6
paul      17      5
bryan     16      8
jenny     16      7

verbal(table2)
[rawscore     scaledscore](fields)
1                1
2                1
3                2
4                2
5                3
6                3
7                4
8                4
9                5
10               5

writen(table3)
[rawscore     scaledscore]fields
1                1
2                1
3                2
4                2
5                3
6                3
7                4
8                4
9                5
10               5
```

basically i want to count how many examinee has a scaled score of 1,2,3,4,5 both for table 2 and 3

Comment: do a COUNT aggregate function query and use group by to scaledscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query.  It will list each scaled score and a count of students even if the count is 0.  Change "FROM verbal" to "FROM written" for the written table.

```
SELECT v.scaledscore as [Scaled Score], count(i.rawscore) as [Count]
FROM verbal v LEFT JOIN basicinfo i ON v.rawscore = i.rawscore
GROUP BY v.scaledscore
```

Comment: i have another question for example that table2 and table3 are in a different .mdb file how can i count then the same way? is it possible?